# Provide reason for downvote

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Encouraging people to explain down-votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-down-votes)

As a new user, I'm still learning the "dos and donts" of posting on here.  I've seen many questions from new users get downvoted with no clear explanation as to why.

I think it would be very useful if it was **mandatory** for a user to provide a reason when they downvote a question/answer.  This would enable the OP to get a better understanding of what they did "wrong" and to help them learn how to do it better next time.

Comment: please note that downvotes here don't mean you have a bad question merely that users disagree with your post

Comment: in this case the downvotes are probably for laughs?

Comment: @jrturton no - it means people don't approve of the request. Also, been asked many times.

Comment: I find the tooltip of the downvote button pretty clear enough. If it would need further clarification, I usually add a comment.

Comment: @Chichiray Isn't that a generalised reason though?  I'm sure that's not the _only_ reason people downvote

Comment: @mcgrailm I don't really see how users disagree with a request for help (I'm referring to the stack overflow parent site)?

Comment: @peachy0685 i was only noting that down votes on meta overflow mean the users disagree

Answer (score 7):

I would support this action but I would insist it be anonymous to prevent retaliation from users. that said I'm not sure that could be done. currently users are encouraged to give a reason but it is not mandatory

Comment: I support this. Especially for newcomers the downvotes are frustrating. There is no learning curve if there is no reason. Personally, I don't care if the comment was public or anonymous. If I have an opinion, I can stand for it and don't fear retaliation.